# ImageMagick code neeeds to be edited..please CHECK OUT

Tags: php, imagemagick

please check my imagemagick code where iam trying to add "size" variable ,but not getting where exactly we need to add size variable just like "color" ,"string"...

```
$animation = new Imagick();
$animation->setFormat( "gif" );
$color = new ImagickPixel( "blue" );
$color->setColor( "red" );
     $string = "kothi!";
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFont( "arial.ttf" );
for ( $i =0; $i <= 0; $i++ )
{
$part = substr( $string,100, $i);

$animation->newImage( 100, 50, $color);

$animation->annotateImage( $draw, 100, 100, 100, $part );
$animation->setImageDelay( 30 );
}
$draw->setFont( "arial.ttf" );
$animation->newImage( 100, 50, $color);
$animation->annotateImage( $draw, 10, 10, 0, $string );
$animation->setImageDelay( 120 );
header( "Content-Type: image/gif" );
echo $animation->getImagesBlob();
```

Comment: "Hell Webmasters"? O.o Oh, and I don't think this has *anything* to do with [tag:javascript], or [tag:html]...it *seems* purely [tag:php] and [tag:imagemagick].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool Imagick::setSize ( int $columns , int $rows )
```

Sets the size of the Imagick object. Set it before you read a raw image format such as RGB, GRAY, or CMYK.

--php.net

Comment: http://jamesroberts.name/blog/2010/05/30/php-imagick-simple-font-rendering-with-automatic-image-canvas-size/